# Can't display this simple .hide() code in Internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been trying this piece of code on a page and it is working fine in Chrome as well as Firefox.

But not in Internet Explorer, only the alert function within the if condition will show up.

```
$('#element-14').change(
 function(){
  $('.late').hide();
  $('.normal').hide();
  var tempDate= new Date();
  var dateViolatetmp = $('#element-14').val();
  var dateViolatearr = dateViolatetmp.split('/');
  var dateViolate= new Date(dateViolatearr[2],(parseInt(dateViolatearr[0],10)-1).toString(),dateViolatearr[1]);
  var one_day=1000*60*60*24;
  var tempDate_unixtime =tempDate.getTime() ;
  var dateViolate_unixtime =dateViolate.getTime();
  var dayDifference = Math.round((tempDate_unixtime/one_day)) - Math.round((dateViolate_unixtime/one_day));
  if(dayDifference<=30){    
    $('.normal').show();
    alert("ok1");
  }
  else{
    $('.late').show();
    alert("ok2");
  }
 });
```

Comment: What is not working? What is #element-14? Does the change event fire? Are there errors in the console?  Also use real words.

Comment: Don't we all love internet explorer?

Comment: could you improve your question? Wat you expect from the code to do. please use real words.

Comment: Is there any reason to use `jQuery()` and `$()` in a same context? may be you have some other libraries loaded ? If you provide a link to your code or make an example will be much easier

Answer (score 0):

Do you see all the values as expected in the console with this code? The reason I wrote `if(console)` conditions is because I'm not sure if it even exists in IE (otherwise would not surprise me a bit(!) and I don't have it installed).

```
$('#element-14').change(function() {
    if (console) console.log('#element-14 changed.');
    $('.late, .normal').hide();
    var arr = $('#element-14').val().split('/');
    if (console) {
        console.log('val:',$('#element-14').val());
        console.log('arr:',arr);
    }
    var dateV = new Date(parseInt(arr[2]), parseInt(arr[0])-1, arr[1]);
    if (console) console.log('dateV:',dateV);
    var one_day = 1000*60*60*24;
    var now = new Date();
    if (console) console.log('now:',now);
    var dayDiff = Math.round((now.getTime()-dateV.getTime()) / one_day);
    if (console) console.log('dayDiff:',dayDiff);
    $(dayDiff <= 30 ? '.normal' : '.late').show();
});
```